# error initialize OFBiz 10.04 without demo data

Tags: initialization, erp, ofbiz

We've tested OFBiz 10.04.05 release on ubuntu 12.04 for a little while and would like to go into beta with it. So I installed OFBiz 10.04.05 and then run `$ ant run-install-extseed
 loaded` just the extseed data.

I am trying to initialize the application. in `https://localhost:8443/ofbizsetup` for Initial Setup

I'm able to fill in the first 2 tabs, `Organization` and `Facility`. However, I have problem with the 3rd tab, `Product Store`. When I fill in the `MyStore` for `"Store Name"` field, I get the following error -

The Following Errors Occurred:

```
Error: Error parsing entity xml file: org.ofbiz.entity.GenericEntityException: 
Error while inserting: [GenericEntity:CarrierShipmentMethod][createdStamp,2013-06-21 11:13:26.664(java.sql.Timestamp)]
[createdTxStamp,2013-06-21 11:13:26.433(java.sql.Timestamp)]
[lastUpdatedStamp,2013-06-21 11:13:26.664(java.sql.Timestamp)]
[lastUpdatedTxStamp,2013-06-21 11:13:26.433(java.sql.Timestamp)]
[partyId,10000(java.lang.String)][roleTypeId,CARRIER(java.lang.String)] 
[sequenceNumber,4(java.lang.Long)]
[shipmentMethodTypeId,LOCAL_DELIVERY(java.lang.String)]
(SQL Exception while executing the following:INSERT INTO CARRIER_SHIPMENT_METHOD 
(SHIPMENT_METHOD_TYPE_ID, PARTY_ID, ROLE_TYPE_ID, SEQUENCE_NUMBER, CARRIER_SERVICE_CODE, LAST_UPDATED_STAMP, LAST_UPDATED_TX_STAMP, CREATED_STAMP, CREATED_TX_STAMP) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
(Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`ofbiz`.`CARRIER_SHIPMENT_METHOD`, CONSTRAINT `CARR_SHMETH_TYPE` FOREIGN KEY 
(`SHIPMENT_METHOD_TYPE_ID`) REFERENCES `SHIPMENT_METHOD_TYPE` 
(`SHIPMENT_METHOD_TYPE_ID`))))  calling service parseEntityXmlFile in importTempDataFile
```

I'm trying to create a store! Anyway, I can't seem to proceed. If I do an `$ ant run-install` then it works fine but it also loads tons of demo data. We want to proceed with OFBiz without all the demo data in it.

What is the best way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

This error says that there is no LOCAL_DELIVERY record in the ShipmentMethodType entity. For a quick fix you could insert the following data with webtools:

```
<ShipmentMethodType description="Local Delivery" shipmentMethodTypeId="LOCAL_DELIVERY"/>
```

But I would recommend to try it with OFBiz 12.04 (I see no reason to use the old OFBiz 10.04.05 version).